There are strange gaps in my terra raster
I am trying to turn a dataframe into a raster. This dataframe is the ML output of another raster. I can confirm that there are the same number of rows and columns, the same CRS, and the same extent.
Here are the rasters:
> r <- rast("./healthydesign-downscaled/hd_039_stratford_tree_downsampled.tif")
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 613, 859, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -81.10008, -80.86859, 43.28595, 43.45115  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : hd_039_stratford_tree_downsampled.tif 
name        : tree 
min value   :  -99 
max value   :    1 

Here is the raster I made using the dataframe:
r <- rast("./healthydesign-downscaled/hd_039_stratford_tree_downsampled.tif")
r1 <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)

# order by x and y 
hi = p2.final[with(p2.final, order(-y,x)), ]

# create a raster 
r2 <- terra::setValues(r, as.matrix(hi$p2))


> r2
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 613, 859, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -81.10008, -80.86859, 43.28595, 43.45115  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : hd_039_stratford_tree_downsampled 
name        :         tree 
min value   : 1.728516e-05 
max value   : 9.972497e-01 

However, when I plot it it has strange gaps, although the original had none:
Original Raster:
plot(r)


New Raster:
plot(r2)


The data SHOULD look different, so that doesn't concern me - but where are the gaps coming from?

Please edit your question to make your code self-contained, minimal, and reproducible.

Probably related to this question?
